# Memory saving working with pointers in Go

Tags: go, memory-management

I would ask if there are some benefits declaring a pointer in reference types (slices, maps, channels, pointers & functions).

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []string{"one", "two"}
    changeValue(0, s)
    fmt.Println(s)

    s = []string{"one", "two"}
    changeValue2(0, &s)
    fmt.Println(s)

}

func changeValue(i int, v []string) {
    v[i] = "newOne"
}

func changeValue2(i int, v *[]string) {
    (*v)[i] = "newOne"
}
```

Both approaches will work, but my question is whether the second one offers any advantages.

The first approach is supposed to create a copy of the slice, but it ultimately works because of the nature of the slice type, which holds pointers inside.

The second approach doesn't create any copies and performs the same operation in the end.
**edit**: I think that statement is not true and the second approach create a copy too but just with a pointer.

Perhaps there is some consensus on this for readability, or maybe the potential improvement is not significant enough to be noticeable.

Comment: *"whether the second one offers any advantages"* -- No, none, not in this example.

Comment: No, but when in doubt: Measure.

Comment: Pointer to slice (e.g. `*[]T`) is useful when the called function needs to change the _slice itself_ (and not necessarily the data its underlying array holds), like changing its length or capacity for example. Another case for pointers to slices is when you have a named slice type (e.g. `type S []T`) and a method implemented on the pointer receiver of that slice type, then you'll need `*S` if you expect to satisfy some interface with that method.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed differences between using a pointer to a slice (or another reference type).

- Avoiding Slice Copying: While both approaches achieve the same result, the second approach using a pointer (*[]string) does not create a copy of the slice itself. Instead, it points to the original slice. In contrast, the first approach ([]string) creates a new copy of the slice when passed as an argument. Here slice refers to the slice header which is the metadata containing capacity, length and the reference to the underlying data.
- Mutability & Intent: Using a pointer allows you to modify the original slice directly, which means the function call can change the slice header.
  This also communicates the intent that this function may modify the original slice and makes it clear that a copy is not being created. It's a way of communicating to the downstream users of this function.